# How to search multiple fields with common terms query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I'm doing a search on multiple fields, I want to avoid common terms and I want to combine results from all fields. Currently, I got this (`cutoff_frequency`, `boost`, `bool must filters`, etc. omitted to make the problem more visible):

```
 {
  query: {
    bool: {
      should: {
        [
          {
            common: {
              title: {
                query: q
              }
            }
          },
          {
            common: {
              description: {
                query: q
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say I have following records:

```
id: 1
title: 'Fox'
description: 'Small fox'

id: 2
title: 'Fox'
description: 'Is quick'

id: 3
title: 'Legendary'
description: 'Quick brown fox'
```

My query is `The quick brown fox`. In the solution above, id 1 and id 2 have the highest score, because they match 2 out of 2 `shoulds`. The record with id 3 has no match in the `title`, so only 1 out of 2 `shoulds` are matched.

The correct order should be

```
id: 3 (matches 3 words)
id: 2 (matches 2 words)
id: 1 (matches 1 word, even tough twice)
```

I don't want to map both fields into a one, because I want to differentiate them in case of a tie, so for example for query `fox`, correct result would be:

```
id: 1 (matches twice)
id: 2 (matches once but in the title)
id: 3 (matches once but in the description)
```

Any suggestions on this would be highly appreciated. Thanks.